# How to migrate to larger disk with different sized partitions?

Tags: partitioning, migration

I currently run Ubuntu 20.04 on a 32GB SSD, which is starting to prove too small as I'm using this machine for more than I originally intended (used to be just an HTPC for Netflix/streaming sites but is now a personal media server). I have a 2TB SSD that I've been storing media on and is mounted at /media, and I'm planning on getting another 2TB SSD and this second one is where I want to migrate the OS to.

My current partitions are ~7GB swap, ~14GB root, and ~7GB for home, but I'd like to partition the new SSD like so:
8GB swap (half of RAM), 46GB root, and 46GB home (I'm assuming that this will be enough for root and home indefinitely) and then the remainder as a second media partition.

Now my question is, is it possible to setup that new partition scheme and clone over the old data such that I can just boost from the new disk and everything will work as it used to, just now with more free space? I.e. will the other drive mounted at /media still mount properly, and will all my services still run without me having to reconfigure them? I know that shifting partitions can cause data loss, and I assume that will be required since I'm increasing the size of all the original partitions (unless there's a way to clone a disk 1 partition at a time? i.e. clone old swap to new larger swap, old root to new larger root, etc.).

I've had this server for a few years and I don't remember all the little things I did to configure it, so I'd really prefer to not have to setup everything again on the new disk.

Comment: I prefer new install & restore from your backups like you have to do when drive fails. Also proves your backup is complete as you still have old install to get something you missed. Image copy, means you cannot reboot with both drives as duplicate UUIDs not allowed. And resizing partitions afterwards can be a hassle. Many suggest clonezilla, but I have not used it.  If you just copy data to new partitions, you then have to edit UUID settings in fstab and reinstall grub. Other settings may also need changes.

Comment: Beware `UUID=` in `/etc/fstab`. Universal Unique ID is different on different disks.

Comment: Is migrating the `/home` partition safer than doing so for root? Because I probably don't need more than 7.7gb added to my root anyways, so would it make sense to just move `/home` to a new drive? Are there any risks to programs breaking due to a new mount point, or just to watch out for data corruption?